# R: extract part of a filename

Tags: r, filenames

I'm trying to extract part of a filename using R, I have a vague idea about how to go about this from here: [extract part of a file name in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055152/extract-part-of-a-file-name-in-r)
however I can't quite get this to work on my list of filenames

example of filenames:

```
"Species Count (2011-12-15-07-09-39).xls"
"Species Count 0511.xls"
"Species Count 151112.xls" 
"Species Count1011.xls" 
"Species Count2012-01.xls" 
"Species Count201207.xls" 
"Species Count2013-01-15.xls"
```

Some of the filenames have a space between Species Count and the date, some without a space, and they are of different lengths and some contain brackets. I just want to extract the numerical part of the filename and to keep the -'s aswell. So for example for the data above I would have:

**Expected output:**

```
2011-12-15-07-09-39 , 0511 , 151112 , 1011 , 2012-01 , 201207 , 2013-01-15
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
regmatches(tt, regexpr("[0-9].*[0-9]", tt))
```

I assume that there are no other numbers in your file names. So, we just search for start of a number and use the greedy operator `.*` so that everything until the last number is captured. This is done using `regexpr` which'll get the position of matches. Then we use `regmatches` to extract the (sub)string out of these matched positions.

---

where `tt` is:

```
tt <- c("Species Count (2011-12-15-07-09-39).xls", "Species Count 0511.xls", 
        "Species Count 151112.xls", "Species Count1011.xls", 
        "Species Count2012-01.xls", "Species Count201207.xls", 
        "Species Count2013-01-15.xls")
```

---

### Benchmarking:

#### Note: Benchmarking results may differ between Windows and *nix machines (as @Hansi notes below under comments).

Quite some nice answers there. So, it's time for benchmarking :)

```
tt <- rep(tt, 1e5) # tt is from above

require(microbenchmark)
require(stringr)
aa <- function() regmatches(tt, regexpr("[0-9].*[0-9]", tt))
bb <- function() gsub("[A-z \\.\\(\\)]", "", tt)
cc <- function() str_extract(tt,'([0-9]|[0-9][-])+')

microbenchmark(arun <- aa(), agstudy <- cc(), Jean <- bb(), times=25)
Unit: seconds
            expr      min       lq   median       uq       max neval
    arun <- aa() 1.951362 2.064055 2.198644 2.397724  3.236296    25
 agstudy <- cc() 2.489993 2.685285 2.991796 3.198133  3.762166    25
    Jean <- bb() 7.824638 8.026595 9.145490 9.788539 10.926665    25

identical(arun, agstudy) # TRUE
identical(arun, Jean) # TRUE
```

Comment: The OT could also try this regex `([a-zA-Z]:(\\w+)*\\[a-zA-Z0_9]+)?.xls` because all his files are `*.xls`

Comment: I think your comment should be directed under the OP's question or as a separate answer.

Comment: This is perfect and a much cleaner way than how I was trying to go about it, thank you!

Comment: Note that adding `perl=TRUE` will get it to run all these solutions faster (`gsub` has the biggest speed boost, albeit slower than others) - not benchmarked here.

Comment: @Hansi, I've tried it on R 3.0.1 Mac Mountain Lion 10.8.3 and now, on Debian Linux cluster R 2.15.2. And the order doesn't change (arun = 2, agstudy = 2.5 and jean = 5.5 seconds).

Comment: Assumed aa,bb,cc in the microbenchmark call didn't notice bb and cc were flipped. Accidentally deleted my comment instead of editing it. Personally I would have used gsub with "[^0-9\\-] but that's only marginally faster than above. str_extract is still faster than regmatches for me.

Comment: To go back to the deleted comment, I'm getting R2.15.2, Win732bit: (arun = 3.4, agstudy = 1.6, jean = 4.7). And R2.15.2 Ubuntu64bit: (arun = 1.3, agstudy = 1.7, jean = 3.7). Seems like the Windows version of base::regmatches is slower than the *nix flavour.

Comment: @Hansi, `stringr` package is a wrapper mostly for base functions. `str_extract` uses `str_locate` which internally uses `regexpr`. So, I don't see how it could be faster, given the function overhead to get to `regexpr`. Conceptually, `gsub` should be slower because it searches for your pattern multiple times (globally) as opposed to `regexpr` (note it's not `gregexpr`).

Comment: Wow, that's interesting. I don't have a windows machine at the moment. But it's definitely interesting to check this difference on different data sets.

Answer (score 5):

Use the function `gsub()` to remove all of the letters, spaces, periods, and parentheses.  Then you will be left with numbers and hyphens.  For example,

```
x <- c("Species Count (2011-12-15-07-09-39).xls", "Species Count 0511.xls", 
    "Species Count 151112.xls", "Species Count1011.xls", "Species Count2012-01.xls", 
    "Species Count201207.xls", "Species Count2013-01-15.xls")

gsub("[A-z \\.\\(\\)]", "", x)

[1] "2011-12-15-07-09-39" "0511"                "151112"             
[4] "1011"                "2012-01"             "201207"             
[7] "2013-01-15"
```

Comment: +1. There's nothing wrong with this answer. Except I try to avoid global search wherever possible. This'll be slower on bigger data. Try doing `tt <- rep(tt, 1e5)` and test this against `regexpr`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're concerned about speed, you can use `sub` with back-references to extract the portions you want.  Also note that `perl=TRUE` is often faster (according to `?grep`).

```
jj <- function() sub("[^0-9]*([0-9].*[0-9])[^0-9]*", "\\1", tt, perl=TRUE)
aa <- function() regmatches(tt, regexpr("[0-9].*[0-9]", tt, perl=TRUE))

# Run on R-2.15.2 on 32-bit Windows
microbenchmark(arun <- aa(), josh <- jj(), times=25)
# Unit: milliseconds
#           expr       min        lq    median        uq       max
# 1 arun <- aa() 2156.5024 2189.5168 2191.9972 2195.4176 2410.3255
# 2 josh <- jj()  390.0142  390.8956  391.6431  394.5439  493.2545
identical(arun, josh)  # TRUE

# Run on R-3.0.1 on 64-bit Ubuntu
microbenchmark(arun <- aa(), josh <- jj(), times=25)
# Unit: seconds
#          expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
#  arun <- aa() 1.794522 1.839044 1.858556 1.894946 2.207016    25
#  josh <- jj() 1.003365 1.008424 1.009742 1.059129 1.074057    25
identical(arun, josh)  # still TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `stringr` package to extract all strings having only digits or digits followed by `-`:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(ll,'([0-9]|[0-9][-])+')

[1] "2011-12-15-07-09-39" "0511"               
    "151112"              "1011"                "2012-01"            
[6] "201207"              "2013-01-15"
```